# Mysql enabling keys got errno 28 for a large table

Tags: indexing, mysql

I have a MYISAM table which is 127GB and the index size is about 149GB. I want to make a copy of it. I tried using mysqldump as well as copying the .MYI, .MYD and .frm files. The former gives me errno 28. I checked the disk has about 300GB free. Physically copying the files results in some junk values which I do not see in the original table. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new disk partition and clone the current drive to the new partition. If you're trying to make a backup instead of just a copy, use a separate physical disk.